# Как заставить работать ViewPager корректно в связке с RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

В приложении 2 окна, в 1-ом мы просматриваем картинки которые отображаются с помощью RecyclerView по вертикали в 2 столбца, при нажатии на любую картинку открывается 2-ое окно на весь экран, где есть возможность уже листать вправо-влево по горизонтали используя ViewPager.

```
**PageFragment**
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "id_test";
    private int pageNumber;
    private int position;
    private Uri source;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id_test");
        source = Uri.parse("android.resource://by.fingers.wallpapers/drawable/" + Images.loadImages[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);

        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        resultView.setImageURI(source);
//        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_view_pager**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext, Images.loadImages);
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**PreviewActivity**

```
public class PreviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.preview_pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PreviewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_preview**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#313130"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PreviewActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/preview_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.Holder> {
    private int[] mItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] itemList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list, null);
        return new Holder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Images.loadImages[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).resize(400, 750).into(holder.view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.mItemList.length;
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView view;

        Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            view = new ImageView(mContext);
            view = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_test", getAdapterPosition());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**PreviewPagerAdapter**

```
class PreviewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int imagesCount = Images.loadImages.length;
    private int[] images = Images.loadImages;

    PreviewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(images[position]);
    }
}
```

**Images**

```
class Images {
    final static int[] loadImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img_01,
            R.drawable.img_02,
            R.drawable.img_03,
            R.drawable.img_04// etc.
    };
}
```

**view_list**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stub"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Сейчас у меня получается что при открытии 2-го окна, если использовать в моем классе PageFragment - `resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);` - то всегда будет открываться картинка первая по счету из массива, если использовать resultView.setImageURI(source); - откроется верная картинка но при пролистывании вправо-влево - картинка не меняется а остается прежней, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать работу VIewPager корректной чтобы всегда открывалась верная картинка и при свайпе картинки менялись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение пройдя через огромные страдания, в `PreviewActivity` я должен был к `viewpager` через `setCurrentItem` установить `position`. Теперь работает как надо!

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id_test"));
```